# How can I get URL Language Code of the current language in joomla php?

Tags: php, joomla, multilingual

I have configured everything that is needed for multilingual website. In the template's code, I see that the link of the logo is pointing to `/` rather than to `/index.php/<language_code>`. Therefore, I wanted to put correct link with the current language code.

My problem is that when I click on the logo it takes me to the default language's main page, rather than taking me to the current language's main page. How can I get it working?

Answer (score -2):

Check if this works with your template

```
<?php
  $app = JFactory::getApplication();
  $lang = JFactory::getLanguage();
  echo $this->language;
?>
```

Good luck!

Comment: Nothing makes sense in the above code. What $this is referred to? Why you need $app and $lang - as you do nothing with them. - and how this answers the OPs question.

Comment: If you add this to a Joomla template it should return the language of the page you are viewing.  It was an attempt to help the OP because I was wanting to troubleshoot the root cause of the problem before suggesting a solution. @Sbpro

Comment: Way late on commenting here, but you're the first two lines of code have nothing to do with the third. In your template, you natively have access to `$this`, which is an instance of the current running document. But inside components, `$this` will refer to the active instance of the component running, and module does not have access to `$this` at all. Context will change what's available.